# Android service unbind, possible to add some extra to the intent?

Tags: java, android, aidl

Is there a way to add some extra when u bind a service?

When you bind the service, you use bindService(intent, serviceConnection, flag). So no problem to add extra and read it. The method onBind(Intent) is called with your intent.

But when you unbind your connection, you use unbindService(serviceConnection), and inside the service the method onUnbind(Intent) is called. Someone know how to catch this intent and add some extra ?

This intent is not the same that we created to bind the service, so the extra are empty.

Any way ?

Comment: No, there is no, more over, as is stated in documentation you will not even get original extras... It seems like XY problem

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. That's sad. For now, I added I extra unbind method in my aidl interface to pass the data before to really unbind. But don't really like this extra step.